# How to recall pushed commit 1 week before?

Tags: git

My local commit history is:

```
commit 5
commit 4
commit 3
commit 2
commit 1
```

Remote gitlab server commit history is:

```
commit 3
commit 2
commit 1
```

`commit 2` was pushed to gitlab server 1 week ago.
Now,I know `commit 2` should not be commited,because content are all Apache tmp files.
How to delete or cancel `commit 2`?
I am new to git,thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest thing to do here would probably be to `git revert` the 2nd commit.  First type `git log` on your branch, which should bring up something like this:

```
f83j2l8f commit 5 comment
439gm93f commit 4 comment
lsm382fs commit 3 comment
lm93nd82 commit 2 comment
9rnj1iu3 commit 1 comment
```

Find the SHA-1 hash of the second commit, which is `lm93nd82` in the example I gave above.  A SHA-1 hash will generally look like some really long unintelligible string.  Now all you have to do is this:

```
git revert lm93nd82
```

This will create a *new* commit on top of your branch, which will functionally undo/erase whatever is was that the 2nd commit introduced.  Now just push your branch as you normally would:

```
git push origin your_branch
```

Now the remote should show a new commit at the HEAD, and the changes which the 2nd commit introduced should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

> There are multiple ways to handle this :

Way 1 : Pull the latest code and remove the diff of commit 2 , diff can be seen in commit 2 on GitHub (easy way) in case of conflicts fix it.

Way 2 : Revert back the commit till commit 2 minus 1 and cheery-pick other commit change-set (Little difficult depends on change-set after commit 2)

Comment: Any advantage of your methods compare  `revert`?

Comment: We can use revert as well but in that case you need to be care full if there are few change-set or files which is reusing your commit 2 changes in that case commits are raised, hence i mentioned there are multiple ways it depends how complex your change sets are